# Why is this program producing a runtime error?

Tags: c

I am writing a C program for doubly linked list. Following code just contain `main` function and `insert` function.

**cfile.c**

```
/*
    In the following code doubly linked list is implemented
*/

//header files
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//create structure for node
struct node{
    int info;
    struct node *LChild;
    struct node *RChild;
}*start;

typedef struct node *NODE;

//function to insert data in the list
void insert(){
    int data;
    NODE q, temp;
    temp = (NODE)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(temp){
        printf("\nEnter the data to be inserted in the list: ");
        scanf("%d", &data);
        temp->info = data;
        temp->RChild = NULL;
    }
    else{
        printf("Out of memory.");
        return;
    }
    if(start == NULL){
        temp->LChild = NULL;
        start->LChild = temp;
        start = temp;
    }
    else{
        q = start;
        while(q->RChild != NULL){
            q = q->RChild;
        }
        q->RChild = temp;
        temp->LChild = q;
    }
    return;
}

//function to insert at the begining
void insert_at_beg(){
    int data;
    NODE temp;
    temp = (NODE)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(temp){
        printf("\nEnter the data to be inserted at the beginning of the list: ");
        scanf("%d", &data);
        temp->info = data;
        temp->LChild = NULL;
        temp->RChild = start;
        start->LChild = temp;
        start = temp;
    }
    else{
        printf("Out of memory.");
    }
    return;
}

//function to insert after a position
void insert_after_pos(){
    int data, pos;
    NODE temp, q;
    printf("\nEnter the position after which data will be inserted: ");
    scanf("%d", &pos);
    q = start;
    for(int i = 0; i < pos-1; i++){
        q = q->RChild;
        if(q == NULL){
            printf("There are less than %d position.", pos);
            return;
        }
    }
    temp = (NODE)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(temp){
        printf("\nEnter the data to be inserted after the %d position: ", pos);
        scanf("%d", &data);
        temp->info = data;
        q->RChild->LChild = temp;
        temp->RChild = q->RChild;
        temp->LChild = q;
        q->RChild = temp;
    }
    return;
}

//function to delete the node
void delete(){
    NODE temp, q;
    int num;
    printf("\nEnter the data to be deleted: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if(start->info == num){
        temp = start;
        start = start->RChild;
        start->LChild = NULL;
        free(temp);
        return;
    }
    q = start;
    while(q->RChild->RChild != NULL){
        if(q->RChild->info == num){
            temp = q->RChild;
            q->RChild = temp->RChild;
            temp->RChild->LChild = q;
            free(temp);
            return;
        }
        q =  q->RChild;
    }
    if(q->RChild->info == num){
        temp = q->RChild;
        free(temp);
        q->RChild = NULL;
        return;
    }
    printf("\nElement %d is not found on this list.", num);
    return;
}

//function to display the list
void display(){
    NODE q;
    if(start == NULL){
        printf("\nList is empty.");
        return;
    }
    q = start;
    while(q != NULL){
        printf("%d ", q->info);
        q = q->RChild;
    }
    return;
}

//function to reverse the list
void reverse(){
    NODE p1, p2;
    p1 = start;
    p2 = p1->RChild;
    p1->RChild = NULL;
    p1->LChild = p2;
    while(p2 != NULL){
        p2->LChild = p2->RChild;
        p2->RChild = p1;
        p1 = p2;
        p2 = p2->LChild;
    }
    start = p1;
    return;
}

int main(){
    int choice;
    char ch;
    start = NULL;
    printf("Menu for doubly linked list");
    do{
        printf("\n1.Insert\n2.Insert at beginning\n3.Insert after position\n4.Display\n5.Delete\n6.Reverse\n7.Exit\nEnter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch(choice){
            case 1: insert();
                    break;
            case 2: insert_at_beg();
                    break;
            case 3: insert_after_pos();
                    break;
            case 4: display();
                    break;
            case 5: delete();
                    break;
            case 6: reverse();
                    break;
            case 7: exit(0);
                    break;
            default: printf("Invalid choice!"); 
        }
        printf("\nDo you want to continue ? ");
        scanf(" %c", &ch);
    }while(ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y');
    return 0;
}
```

On compiling the above code with `gcc cfile.c` it is compiling successfully. 
But it is producing runtime error. On debugging with `gdb` I came to know that there is some error at line 28. Unfortunately I cannot understand what's the error. It's showing

```
Program received signal 
SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000010040116a in insert () at cfile.c:28
28          start->LChild = temp;
```

I know it has to do something with the dereferencing pointer.

But why ? whats wrong with this code, I have done `start = NULL` before calling `insert` function.

Here is the stackdump

```
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at rip=0010040116A
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=00000000FFFFCC40 rcx=0000000600018040
rdx=0000000600028460 rsi=00000006000283B0 rdi=0000000000000000
r8 =00000000FFFFB5FC r9 =000000018013E150 r10=0000000100000000
r11=000000010040111C r12=00000000FFFFCC61 r13=0000000000000000
r14=00000000FFFFCC61 r15=000000018021AE83
rbp=00000000FFFFCBC0 rsp=00000000FFFFCB80
program=E:\Learning\Languages\C\a.exe, pid 8612, thread main
cs=0033 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
Stack trace:
Frame        Function    Args
000FFFFCBC0  0010040116A (000FFFFCC61, 00000000000, 000FFFFCC61, 000FFFFCCC0)
000FFFFCBF0  001004011E6 (00000000020, FF0700010302FF00, 00180047891, 00000000000)
000FFFFCCC0  00180047902 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
00000000000  00180045693 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
000FFFFFFF0  00180045744 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
End of stack trace
```

I don't know anything about the stackdump. So I am unable to understand it.

**gcc version**: 5.4.0
**gdb version**: 7.10.1

Answer (score 5):

In this block:

```
if(start == NULL){
    temp->LChild = NULL;
    start->LChild = temp; // <<< `start` is NULL here !!!
    start = temp;
}
```

you are trying to dereference `start` while it is still `NULL`, hence the seg fault.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve with the code at this point - since you didn't comment it at all no one can really guess your intent, but it looks like you are trying to insert a node and your logic is muddled.

Comment: If you are not clear about the steps then try drawing it out on paper first.

Answer (score 1):

The "SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault" is something like an invalid pointer access or in your case a simple Null Pointer Exception known in other programming languages.

So you can't access members of a null pointer obviously.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you (in several places) use a pointer without making sure that it isn't `NULL`. Code like this:

```
NODE start = NULL;
start->LChild = ....whatever....;
```

will cause a runtime error as you are dereferencing a `NULL` pointer.

So when working with pointers the important lesson is:

> Always make sure that a pointer is pointing to something valid before dereferencing it

The answer from @PaulR already tells you one place where your code is wrong but... there are more.

**In insert() (as already mentioned by @PaulR)**

```
if(start == NULL){
    temp->LChild = NULL;
    start->LChild = temp; // ups, start is NULL
                          // You probably just need to delete this line
                          // as all you want is to make start equal to temp
    start = temp;
}
```

**In insert_at_beg()**

```
    temp->RChild = start;
    start->LChild = temp; // ups, start may be NULL
                          // you need to add a check here like
                          // if (start != NULL) start->LChild = temp;
    start = temp;
```

**In insert_after_pos()**

```
q = start;                // start may be NULL
for(int i = 0; i < pos-1; i++){
    q = q->RChild;        // so here you may be using a NULL pointer
```

So before going into the loop you need to check `start` is `NULL` and return if it is.

**In delete()**

```
if(start->info == num){  // ups, start may be NULL
                         // Add a check
```

**In reverse()**

```
p1 = start;        // start may be NULL
p2 = p1->RChild;   // ups....
                   // Add a check
```

Some other comments:

1) typedef'ing a pointer into the name `NODE` is very unclear for other readers of your code. Avoid it! Or at least use a name that clearly tells that it is a pointer, e.g. `NODE_P`

2) Always check the value returned by `scanf`. Example:

```
if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1)
{
    // Input error
    ....
    Add error handling here
    ....
}
```